Is there a way to send the query to gemini/bard through url?
Is there a way to send the query to gemini/bard through url? like ?q="How to say xyz"?
Any one ever did similar work before?

Although I'm not sure about the scale of your actual situation, as a very simple approach, how about using Web Apps created by Google Apps Script? Ref When this is used, you can obtain the generated content using the query parameter like ?q=How to say xyz. But, I'm not sure whether this approach is not suitable for your actual situation. So, I proposed this approach as a comment. I apologize for this situation.

The Gemini API does not provide a way for you to do so directly.
You can, of course, create your own webapp that takes a query parameter, sends it to the Gemini API (either as is or with any additional prompting you wish), and does whatever you wish with the result that comes back.
Keep in mind that this is fine for one-shot queries, but if you expect to then use it as part of a chat session you'll need to manage the chat history as well.

I spent half an hour searching for a solution to this. You can't! In Chrome, all you can do is use @gemini <question>.
As of today, there is no other way :(
